# Как найти значения, которые состоят только из цифр или только из латинских букв A-Z без учета регистра?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

В таблице надо найти значения, которые состоят только из цифр или только из латинских букв (A-Z, без учета регистра).

```sql
SELECT model, type
FROM Product
WHERE model NOT like '%[^A-Z]%' OR model not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Как переписать условие с `LIKE` через регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 4):

Воспроизводимый [пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a9e55dc04c5f3bd27aa04dea37bc494) поможет понять, как переписать на регулярное выражение:

```
with t (col) as (
    select 'Abc'  from dual union all -- ok
    select '123'  from dual union all -- ok
    select 'A123' from dual union all -- смесь латинские и цифры
    select 'abcÜ' from dual union all -- символ латинский, но не английский
    select 'ab c' from dual union all -- пробел
    select 'Аbc'  from dual           -- русский символ А
    )
select col, case when regexp_like (col, '^([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+)$') 
                 then 'yes' 
                 else 'no' end matched
from t;
```

Где:

- `[A-Za-z]+` - только латинские символы английского алфавита
- `|` - или
- `[0-9]+` - только цифры

Даст в результате:

```
COL   MATCHED 
----- --------
Abc   yes     
123   yes     
A123  no      
abcÜ  no      
ab c  no      
Аbc   no
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT model, type
FROM Product
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^[A-Z]+$', 'i')
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^[0-9]+$')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `LIKE` вам нужен `REGEXP_LIKE`

```sql
SELECT model, type
FROM Product
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^[a-z]+$', 'i') OR
  REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^\d+$')
```

Или даже так

```sql
SELECT model, type
FROM Product
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(model, '^([a-z]|\d)+$', 'i')
```